Rigorous treatment of the modern history of deep learning
In light of:

the recent Nobel Prize in Physics awarded to Hinton and Hopfield
the controversy in the machine learning community around the history following this review article: "Deep Learning", Lecun, Bengio, Hinton, 2015 and an answer review by Schmidhuber.

I was curious whether there was already work on this topic from professional historians instead of (interested) first parties.
I was unable to find anything beyond these two reviews and several low-quality presentations in either reference manuals or websites providing introductions or tutorials for machine learning.
Thank you for your help.

In his abstract, Schmidhuber lists "the chain rule (1676)"... He's taking a very big swing.

Perheps to ask for a "real historical approach" is too much... see Md Zahangir Alom etc The History Began from AlexNet: A Comprehensive Survey on Deep Learning Approaches (2018)
